# How to find the second most frequent character in java?

Tags: java, algorithm

What I am trying to achieve is, when there is a given word, I need to find out the second most frequent character within that string.

In additions to that, there is some more options I want to achieve. For example,

1. If a string, "ababababd" is given, there are **four** '**a**'s, **four**  '**b**'s, and **one** '**d**', so in this case, I need to printout '**d**'.
2. If a string is "ababababdc" is given, there are **four**  '**a**'s, **four**  '**b**'s, **one** '**d**' **and** '**c**', I need to printout '**dc**'

   ```
   public class MemorizeWorld {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
       Solution solution = new Solution();
       String a = "ababababd";
       solution.solution(a);
    }
   }

   class Solution {
        public void solution(String a) {
            int[] array = new int[26];
            char[] char_array = a.toCharArray();

            for(int i = 0; i < char_array.length; i++) {
                int index = char_array[i] - 'a';
                array[index]++;
            }
            int max = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if(array[i] > max) {
                    max = array[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```

This is what I have done so far and I am stuck on getting a solution. I know how to get the second most frequent character by following the post from geeksforgeeks, but I don't know how I should apply those two options above to that. Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?

Comment: You already found max, so now all you need to do is find another max which is smaller than previous max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the second maximum just like you've found the maximum.

```
int max2 = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] > max2 && array[i] < max) {
         max2 = array[i];
     }
}
```

Then get the result string whose frequency is same as the second maximum.

```
String result = "";
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] == max2) {
         result += (i + 'a');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stream API may be used in this solution:

1. create a frequency map using `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.summingInt / Collectors.counting()`
2. "invert" the frequency and character using `Collectors.toMap` or `Collectors.groupingBy` + `Collectors.joining` to merge characters with the same frequency; use a `TreeMap` with the reversed key comparator
3. skip the first value referring the max frequency, and return the next one:

```java
public static String get2ndMostFrequent(String str) {
    if (null == str || str.length() < 2) {
        return null;
    }
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("")) // Stream<String> chars
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            s -> s, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.summingInt(s -> 1)
        ))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getValue,
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2,
            () -> new TreeMap<Integer, String>(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        ))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .skip(1)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
}
```

Tests:

```java
for (String s : Arrays.asList("ababababd", "ababdababc", "dabbcacd", "acbdagh")) {
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + get2ndMostFrequent(s));
}
```

Output

```
ababababd -> d
ababdababc -> dc
dabbcacd -> null  // no 2nd frequency
acbdagh -> cbdgh
```